# Cc header in wp_mail() not working

Tags: wp-mail

for some reason, the Cc email address won't receive the same mail as the recipient.

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8',
    'Cc: finance@example.com',
    'From: IFHC <noreply@example.com>'
);

wp_mail(
    $receiver,
    $addonList[$addonId]['Description'],
    $message,
    $headers
);
```